# Sketch - Text not resizing with symbol

Tags: text, sketch-app, interface-design, resize

**Summary**

I'm trying to resize a symbol in Sketch and the text is not resizing with the symbol.  I have "adjust content on resize" enabled and it's still not working.

**What I've tried**

1. I've also tried making the text into a symbol with "adjust content on resize" enabled and that's not helping either.
2. I've also tried "cmd + k" to change the scale and it's not scaling down the text properly.

**Additional Information**

The text is setup as a global text style in my sketch file, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Did you try to group symbol and text?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues and noticed that I had my text and other layers nested in groups, probably from detaching from old symbols and creating new ones. Once I removed all the nested groups, the text resized.

Answer (score 0):

I made a symbol with a single text tried to scale it with "cmd + K" and it worked perfectly. please make sure that your text setting is like this.

[image: sketch setting for scaling]

I tried it on Sketch version 56.2

Answer (score 0):

You actually might be interested in a brand new feature only available on the latest Sketch Beta (Sketch 58) as of today, September 1st.

Here's the link to that beta: https://www.sketch.com/beta/

As you can see :

> Introducing Smart Layout With Smart Layout, we’re making Symbols more powerful and supercharging your workflow when it comes to using them in your designs. With it, you can set a direction for Symbols to resize when you change their overrides, while keeping the spacing between different layers in that Symbol consistent.

That allows you to create something like this : https://gfycat.com/fr/likablescalyjay (I'm sorry it's not embedded, but it seems imgur does not want to upload the gif version of it...)

High quality version : https://giant.gfycat.com/LikableScalyJay.webm

So, to create a symbol that will resize correctly with some text inside, you now have new options called `Smart Layout` either when creating the symbol or after thanks to its settings.

[image: Sketch 58 Smart Layout]

You can then override its text and... tadaa! It will resize automatically.

[image]

I know it's not the best answer since **Sketch 58** is still in Beta but you can download it and use it as a separate application.

Comment: That's actually the opposite of what the OP is asking for. The question is how to make the TEXT resize with the rest of the symbol; not the other way around.